# Menu doesn't want to work with funcion

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu, menu

I am doing a menu based program and I am trying to call a function as one of the menu choice. In this case it is the first choice. However if I press 1 nothing happens, but the script works( I have tested it). When I press 2 program exists and if I press any number different than 1 or 2 it gives a warning that it is not a valid choice.

Could you guys help?
Thank You

```
#!/bin/bash


one() {
who |
    awk '
        { User [$1]++; }
        BEGIN { printf "|%-15s| |%15s|\n\n", "Username", "Session Count" }
        END { for (i in User) printf "|%-15s| |%15s|\n", i, User [i] }
    '
}


while [ 1 ]
do
    clear
    echo "1. Display current users with session counts"
    echo "2. Exit"
    read -p "Enter your menu choice [1 - 2]:" choice
    case $choice in 
        1)
            one;;
        2)
            exit 0;;
        *)    read -p "Wrong selection!!! Press [Enter] to continue..." dummyChoice;;
    esac  
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is fine. Just that the `clear` statement you have *clears* the screen and hence you can't see the output corresponding to case `1`.

Remove the `clear` or

add a `read` statement before continuing in the loop:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    clear
    echo "1. Display current users with session counts"
    echo "2. Exit"
    read -p "Enter your menu choice [1 - 2]:" choice
    case $choice in 
        1)
            one;;
        2)
            exit 0;;
        *)    read -p "Wrong selection!!! Press [Enter] to continue..." dummyChoice;;
    esac  
    read # so you can see the output before the next iteation
done
```

Comment: Thank You. It works, but how can I clear the screen instead? I want it to look nice

Comment: The `read` as in answer will wait for you to input something. Once you press a key, then it'll *clear* the screen due to the clear statement at the start of the loop.

Comment: Great ! Thank you one more time

Answer (score 1):

May be adding clear statement in start of function "One" work